# Python | script to get font family that is getting rendered on webpage

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

Using python requests I am fetching webpage contents, however I also want to know what font  family is being utilized for which element on the webpage, is there an easy method to get it?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Yes, you can use `value_of_css_property("font-family")` to get it. You can also check the [documentation][1] to get more details.


  [1]: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property